# JSON включает обратные слеши "\" и лишние кавычки.Как избавиться?

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, сериализация

Всем привет.

После сериализации, JSON включает в себя "\" и лишние кавычки ,которые потом отображаются в постмане.

Я использовал ApiСontroller

код:

```
public class HomeController : ApiController
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")]
    public string Index()
    {
        Person obj = new Person();
        obj.Id = 1;
        obj.Name = "Bob";
        string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
        return output;
    }
}
```

вот,как отображает в постмане

```
"{\"id\":1,\"name\":\"Bob\"}"
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Также я попробовал сделать без  ApiController:

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    // GET: /<controller>/
    [HttpGet]
    [Route("test")]
    public string Index()
    {
        Person obj = new Person();
        obj.Id = 1;
        obj.Name = "Bob";
        string output = new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(obj);
        return output;
    }
}
```

В постмане он отображает правильно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно ли как-то избавиться от этого,используя именно ApiController?

Заранее спасибо

Comment: 1. Это RUso, вопросы принято задавать тут на русском. Переводите, либо он будет рано или поздно закрыт. 2. Вы где смотрите, в студии в моменте отладки? Там естественно будут слешы, ибо в string не может быть скобок без экранизации. Но на выходе, если вы выведите это значение куда либо - у вас будет чистый JSON без слешей.

Comment: @Karen I'm sorry, but It is resource is intended for Russian language. Please try to use your question in English version resource: [stackoverflow.com](https://stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: А как ваш output попадает в постман? Покажите более полный код

Comment: чем вам не нравятся слеши? слеши - это экранирование..так что все ок, и json валидный

Comment: Что такое `obj`? Наверняка это уже готовый json - строка в этом формате. После повторной конвертации в json добавляются слеши.

Comment: @ВиталийШебаниц, они там лишние. По какой-то причине оно дважды оборачивается. Сначала получается правильный json, который оказывается в переменной `output`, а потом она ещё раз оджейсонивается и отправляется на клиент в том виде, который на скриншоте.

Comment: @Karen, а если `public object Index()` или `public Person Index()`, а внутри `return obj;`?

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, вопрос обновился.

Comment: В WebAPI возвращаемый результат автоматически сериализуется в некоторый формат. Зависит от разных настроек. В частности, смотрите [Action Results](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/getting-started-with-aspnet-web-api/action-results), [Content Negotiation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/content-negotiation)

Answer (score 1):

Сдаётся мне, что `ApiController` умеет сам оджейсонивать объекты (а также сериализовывать в других форматах в соответствии с запросом клиента), поэтому надо сделать

```
public Person Index()
```

```
return obj;
```

Comment: Да, наверняка это сработает.